# Problems converting SQL to LINQ to Entities statement

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

We are in the process of converting SQL / Stored Procedures to LINQ to Entities statements.

Currently I am converting this SQL:

```
declare @startDate DateTime
set @startDate = DATEADD(DD, -30, GETDATE())

select h.*
from  History h (nolock) 
  inner join Quote q (nolock) on h.QuoteID = q.QuoteID 
  inner join Agency (nolock) a on q.AgencyID = a.AgencyID
  inner join DC_PLT_EntityRoles er (nolock) on a.AgencyID = er.EntityID
  inner join DC_PLT_Roles (nolock) r on er.RoleID = r.RoleID
where
  q.Status = 'Inforce' 
  and q.LOB = 'Vacant'  
  and q.EffectiveDate > @startDate 
  and h.Deleted is null 
  and h.DeprecatedBy is null 
  and h.TransactionStatus = 'Committed'
  and r.Name = 'Wholesaler'
```

This is the LINQ to Entities which I wrote up:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);    
var results = (from h in Histories
       .Include("Quote")
       .Include("Quote.Agency")
       .Include("Quote.Agency.DC_PLT_Roles")
   where h.Quote.Status == "Inforce" &&  
              h.Quote.LOB == "Vacant" &&        
              h.Quote.EffectiveDate > startDate &&
              h.Deleted == null &&
              h.DeprecatedBy == null &&
              h.TransactionStatus == "Committed" && 
              h.Quote.Agency.DC_PLT_Roles.All(r => r.Name == "Wholesaler")
   select h).ToList();
```

The problem is the SQL returns 77 rows and my LINQ returns none.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can convert this correctly? Or what I am missing.

Thanks for your help.

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h.Quote.Agency.DC_PLT_Roles.All(r => r.Name == "Wholesaler")`

I think this line is your problem.  I'm pretty sure you want to use `Any` here not `All`.  In this instance `All` means all DC_PLT_Roles for the Agency must have `Name == "Wholesaler"`.  `Any` means there must be one DC_PLT_Role for the agency with `Name == "Wholesaler"`.

Comment: That did it. You rock!!!! I honestly tried to narrow down my search of the problem by commenting out different lines and I thought I tried that one. However, it got me no where. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You might also wanna check out this in regards to the (nolock) statements:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingLINQToSQLAndLINQToEntitiesToUseNOLOCK.aspx